# System.NullReferenceException error in Program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, visual-studio-2012

In my program, I'm getting the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in POS    System.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This happens when I try to add something to TransactionList as shown below. TransactionList is a list of class instances, declared like this:

`public static List<Transaction> TransactionList { get; set; }`

And this is the Transaction class:

```
class Transaction
{
    public double TotalEarned { get; set; }
    public double TotalHST { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int DaysSince2013 { get; set; }
}
```

Any clue whats wrong here? I can't seem to find why this error is being thrown... Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < (lines / 5); i++)
        {
            TransactionList.Add(new Transaction //Error happens on this line
            {
                TotalEarned = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5)]),
                TotalCost = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 1]),
                TotalHST = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 2]),
                Category = stringArray[(i * 5) + 3],
                DaysSince2013 = Convert.ToInt32(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4])
            });
        }
```

Comment: Use the debugger: either `TransactionList` or `stringArray` are most likely `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just initialize it before your `for loop` ?

```
if (TransactionList == null)
   TransactionList = new List<Transaction>();

for (int i = 0; i < (lines / 5); i++)
        {
            TransactionList.Add(new Transaction //Error happens on this line
            {
                TotalEarned = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5)]),
                TotalCost = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 1]),
                TotalHST = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 2]),
                Category = stringArray[(i * 5) + 3],
                DaysSince2013 = Convert.ToInt32(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4])
            });
        }
```

Or if you don't like that, since you've declared it as `static`, you could do:

```
public static List<Transaction> TransactionList = new List<TransactionList>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **initilize the list** before using it. When you get Object reference not set to an instnce error, it means the object physically doesnot exist

Answer (score -2):

Proprably TransactionList and or stringArray are both null.

try to do this

public static List TransactionList { get; set; }

```
if(TransactionList  == null)
   TransactionList  = new List<Transaction>();
```

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: You cant initialize auto-properties like this.

Comment: If you re-work your answer and format your code correctly, I will remove the down vote.